# ASP.NET Core 2.0.0 Angular app showing HTTP Error 502.5 when hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, iis, deployment

I am stuck trying to publish this legacy project to folder, and host it on IIS locally. I get an HTTP error 502.5.

I have uninstalled all the newer SDKs and only have 2.0.0 installed at this time. I have installed webhost and runtime for .NET Core 2.0.0 and .NET 6.0.3.

I've been looking for a solution on the web indicated me that "Error 502.5" is either related to a wrong or missing SDK, or a problem with `web.config`.

I cannot identify any problem with the `web.config` (I am attaching my config file below). I created a simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project for testing and it is deploying without any error. It is a project developed by someone else and I am not wholly familiar with it, and trying to just deploy it on our local server. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false">
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" maxUrl="40960" maxQueryString="20480" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00">
            <environmentVariables />
        </aspNetCore>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Edit:
I am including the log I found after one of the failed attempts below.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module
Date:          10/03/2022 09:44:00
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      LAPTOP-XXX-TANZIB
Description:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXXTEST' with physical root 'C:\XXX Builds\Build-3\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\XXX Builds\Build-3\Web.exe ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-03-10T09:44:00.9621312Z" />
    <EventRecordID>16307</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="31784" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP-XXX-TANZIB</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXXTEST' with physical root 'C:\XXX Builds\Build-3\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\XXX Builds\Build-3\Web.exe ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Based on your description, I'm afraid to determine the cause of the problem. If possible, could you provide relevant log info or error message?  For example in the configuration you mentioned, modify stdoutLogEnabled="false" to `enable` for logging. Or change the app hosting model, just right click the project and select `properties` -> select `Debug` tab -> modify Hosting Model to `In Process` or `Out of Process`.

Comment: Thank you @Xudong Peng. Yes I have enabled stdoutLogEnabled by setting it to true. But I am finding it hard to locate the log entries. The project being old, some of the dependencies are deprecated, could that be the problem? But then again it is launching in IIS Express when I run debug through Visual Studio 2017. I am going to try a new self contained build now and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have added the log I found after one the new builds